# Why does gnome-sushi use that much memory?

Tags: memory-usage, previews, gnome-sushi

I noticed that the Sushi (gnome-sushi) previewer uses around 60MB of RAM and wondered why it has to be so much memory, as I can only preview a single image/sound file at a time?

eog (eye-of-gnome) the default picture viewer uses around 30MB and deadbeef a lightweight music player around 10MB RAM and they aren't that much slower in showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a real solution to my question but it nicely solves what I wanted to accomplish.

I found Gloobus to replace Gnome-Sushi with [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/using-gloobus-preview-with-nautilus-32.html) very nice intructions, which is lot more lightweight.